# Nullpointer though widget is initialised correctly

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I am trying to populate a list view. Given below is the code. I get null pointer exception. On debugging, I found that mListView is null. I am uncertain why mListview is null even though the list is initialised correctly.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity 
{
    private IndexableListView mListView;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        List<string> mItems = new List<string> ();
        mItems.Add("Diary of a Wimpy Kid 6: Cabin Fever");
        mItems.Add("Steve Jobs");
        mItems.Add("Inheritance (The Inheritance Cycle)"); 
        ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(this,         Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItems);
        mListView = (IndexableListView) FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
         mListView.Adapter = adapter;
```

The last line in the code above where I am setting the adapter - in there mListview is null and gives me exception. Any help is much appreciated.
PS: The code above is for Xamarin

Comment: Check your *Main.xml* if you have a *IndexableListView* tag with *listview* as id.

Comment: Can you give us the XML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout - `Resource.Layout.Main`, doesn't contain `ListView` with id = `listview`.